# Date Popup does not translate date format

Tags: entities, datetime, i18n-l10n

I am using date popup for a Italian site.
In edit/node when in my_data_field I select the date it shows in English format mm/dd/YY and not in dd/mm/YYYY.

Instead if I use the date popup in a exposed filter in the display view works as I expected.

The problem occour only in edit/node .

Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salve!
You only need to configure this in the field's settings, under MORE SETTINGS AND VALUES.

Here is a screenshot that shows that the option you are looking for is available in the drop down list:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Damned, you are right! It's easy and obvious! :-) Thank you @Stefanos Petrakis